# Can I use a different version of Node in the: IBM Bluemix DevOps Services, build step 'npm' builder type?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, devops

I am building an ember application and then packaging it into a WAR file for deployment to a liberty runtime.

The ember build process warns me that ember-cli will cease to work with node v0.10.29 and recommends using node 0.12.

**Can I use a different version of Node in the: DevOps Services, build step 'npm' builder type?**

> Future versions of Ember CLI will not
>   support v0.10.29. Please update to
>   Node 0.12 or io.js. version: 0.2.7
>   1.13.8
>
> Could not find watchman, falling back
>   to NodeWatcher for file system events.
>   Visit
>   http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for
>   more info.
>   BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...BuildingBuilding.(node)
>   warning: Recursive process.nextTick
>   detected. This will break in the next
>   version of node. Please use
>   setImmediate for recursive deferral.
>   (node) warning: Recursive
>   process.nextTick detected. This will
>   break in the next version of node.
>   Please use setImmediate for recursive
>   deferral. ... (repeated node warnings)
>   ... (node) warning: Recursive
>   process.nextTick detected. This will
>   break in the next version of node.
>   Please use setImmediate for recursive
>   deferral.
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded Build step 'Execute shell'
>   marked build as failure Finished:
>   FAILURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v0.10.29 is the only version of node that exists on the build image. In order to use a different version the user must download it. Here is an example script of how to do that

```
#!/bin/bash
node_version=v0.12.7
install_name=node-v0.12.7-linux-x64
if [ ! -e $install_name.tar.gz ]; then
wget "http://nodejs.org/dist/$node_version/$install_name.tar.gz"
echo 'Untarring'
tar xf $install_name.tar.gz
fi
NODE_12_INSTALL_DIR=`pwd`/$install_name/bin
PATH=$NODE_12_INSTALL_DIR:$PATH
node -v
```

Answer (score 1):

What node version did you specify in your `package.json`? Bluemix supports all currently available node versions, look at [the docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/nodejs/index.html#nodejs) under "Node.js runtime versions" for more information. Go ahead and specify the needed version in your `package.json` as an `engines` property and you should be fine.

Comment: I have specified the version I want in `packages.json` as an `engines` property: `">= 0.12.0"`. 
The Node.js version when building the app is different to the Node.js runtimes available to run your app. I want to change the Node.js version when building the app in the IBM DevOps Services (previously jazzhub.net).

Comment: Right, well you can specify the buildpack either with the `-b` option of the Cloud Foundry CLI or in your `manifest.yml` with the `buildpack` option. Both the IBM SDK for node (sdk-for-nodejs_v2_5-20150902-1526) and the CloudFoundry  [community buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack) should work.

Comment: specifying the buildpack is helpful for selecting the version of node to use at Runtime: [Buildpacks provide framework and runtime support for your applications](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/).
I want to change the version that is supplied by IBM DevOps pipeline.