# How to update Node.js version in Bluemix when running test job

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In "The IBM® Bluemix® DevOps Services Build & Deploy feature", I have stage named "Run tests". And in that stage I created Test job.

But [my unit tests fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmKxD.png)...

It's because Node.js version is too old to understand ES2015 syntax, I guess. 
So I wanna update Node.js version to 6.x

But I don't know how. Maybe I have to add some lines in [test command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlKr4.png)

Could anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version in your package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "consolidate": "0.10.0",
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "swig": "1.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.7",
    "npm": "2.7.4"
  }
}
```

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already set package.json like that. When I run "node -v" in test running environment, then I got "0.10.40".

Comment: And I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290994/can-i-use-a-different-version-of-node-in-the-ibm-bluemix-devops-services-build/33895081?stw=2#33895081 Thanks @RamVennam